# Asp.net c# : ListBox showing only one item

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, listbox

I've this program with two web forms. I take the data from one of the web forms through

```
public GigOpportunity GetData()
{
    //Get written data from text boxes from this web form to the other
    return new GigOpportunity(txtBoxID.Text, Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date,
        TextBoxVenue.Text, TextBoxGenre.Text, Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxCost.Text),
        Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxCapacity.Text), CheckHeadLiner.Checked,
        TextBoxMainAct.Text, CheckEngineer.Checked);
}

public void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // First part: Saves info on first page.
    Session.Add("Gig", GetData());
    // First part: Saves info on first page.
    GigManagerWebForm.add = true;
    Server.Transfer("~/GigManagerWebForm.aspx");
}
```

And I get it to another form through this,

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gigList = new GigList();

    AddGig();
}

private void UpdateList()
{
    lstGigs.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < gigList.Count(); i++)
    {
        lstGigs.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(gigList.getGig(i)));
    }
}

public void AddGig()
{

    if (add == true)
    {
        //Reads info into variables on the second page.
        GigOpportunity getData = (GigOpportunity)(Session["Gig"]);

        gigList.addGig(getData);
        add = false;

        //Create new session ID
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));

    }
    UpdateList();

}
```

I simply have no clue why my list only shows me the one item that I lastly add.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in UpdateList method you clears out the list and you add elements from gigList but on every Page_Load gigList becames new List and addGig adds to it only one item. To resolve the issue you have you probably ought to not clear the ListBox before you add new element. Alternatively you might want to store whole list (not only last added element) in a session. You might as well save that List to ViewState.

I tried the following simplified code on my application and it worked:

```
public void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // First part: Saves info on first page.
        if (Session["Gig"] == null)
        {

            Session.Add("Gig", new List<string>());
        }
        List<string> list = (List<string>)Session["Gig"];
        list.Add("new Data");
        Session["Gig"] = list;
        Server.Transfer("~/GigManagerWebForm.aspx");
    }

// On the GigManagerWebForm.aspx
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddGig();
    }

public void AddGig()
    {
        if(Session["Gig"] != null)
        {
            //Reads info into variables on the second page.
            List<string> getData = (List<string>)(Session["Gig"]);

            ListBox1.Items.AddRange(getData.Select(d => new ListItem(d)).ToArray());

            Session["Gig"] = getData;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Deleted the clear in update and the same thing happens...I still have just one item in the listbox

Comment: You need to store somewhere (for instance in Session) the whole List - it won't be stored in ViewState, as you are going in between to different pages. To add new data you go to Adding form which discards ViewState (and ListBox items collection with it) for GigManagerWebForm.aspx. Try my solution - it works with strings and you need to rearange it to work with your data class.

Comment: I did try it and it does work adding an item called "new Data". Now I've tried to change everything to my code and make it of type GigOpportunity but I cant seem to make it work...Lists are just so not my thing. Thanks for the help by the way

Comment: Instead of using Select statement (if you are not familiar with linq) you may use your structure with for loop, or even better foreach loop. You may convert each GigOpportunity element to string and add it with list.Items.Add method.

Answer (score 0):

In Page_Load you initalize a new GigList to the gigList variable. In AddGig you add a new GigOpportunity to it.

Then in UpdateList, you clear the lstGigs, and add whatever is in gigList to it. There's only one item in gigList, which is the one you just added. That's the reason you're only seeing the last item.

Where and how is lstGigs initialized? It should be populated from some kind of storage before you try to add the new item.